# Xamarin Xaml Formatting Standart

Tags: xamarin.forms

How should be Xamarin Xaml Formatting Standart like be?

For example I will share two same code with different formatting. Which one should I prefer and why?

```
<!-- One Line Formatting -->
  <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Welcome, good to see you" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkIndigo}" Style="{StaticResource LabelLight}" />
          <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding UserName}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkIndigo}" Style="{StaticResource LabelExtraBold}"/>
   </Grid>


<!-- Separating lines -->

 <Grid Grid.Row="0" 
       RowSpacing="0">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Label Text="Welcome, good to see you" 
              Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" 
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
              TextColor="{StaticResource DarkIndigo}" 
              Style="{StaticResource LabelLight}" />
       Label Text="{Binding UserName}" 
             Grid.Row="1" 
             FontSize="24" 
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
             TextColor="{StaticResource DarkIndigo}"
             Style="{StaticResource LabelExtraBold}"/>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: I will talk about their respective strengths and weaknesses, and which one depends on you. The first advantage is that the code occupies a small number of lines, it seems that the interface is simple, the first-level parameter preview is fast, and the disadvantage is that the secondary parameter reading is slow. The second advantage is that it is convenient to read all the parameters of the code, but it is convenient to find the problem, but at the same time, the display interface occupies a large number of rows and does not seem to be concise.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite opinion based, but per my experience and personal test, I would advise to use the second option.

The biggest advantage is related to easily seing all the attributes related to an element, without the need for scroll (imagine having a small screen or such).

Answer (score 0):

The second option is better, as it's easier to read.

Just keep in mind, if somebody would use your code, he/she won't be thankful because of long lines to read.

As for me, I use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=CjwKCAjwhbHlBRAMEiwAoDA345B6IXA57ClJXUP3cqojJMzxagwijr6ORCT1BbFZZ9KKSkaUuIvawBoCoPkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), that could do code formatting for me. You should try that to!